# Select element from list in Pandas Series based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, list, indexing

I have a Pandas DataFrame of the following form:

```
  Name         Dates        Trigger
  John       [d1,d2,d3]     1
  Mike       [d4]           NaN
  Li         [d1,d4,d5]     2
```

where the rows in the column *Dates* are Python lists, where each element in the lists is a DateTime object (e.g. '2019-08-15').

My final goal is to obtain an array with the differences (in days) between the *Dates* at the index position mentioned in *Trigger*, resulting in a new column like:

```
       Date_diff
   [d2-d1,d2-d2,d2-d3]
   [NaN]/d4
   [d5-d1,d5-d4,d5-d5]
```

No matter what I've tried, I always failed to properly identify the correct element in the list based on the last column. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After handling the NaN's, the following solution works:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.Dates[row.Trigger], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to take the Trigger as the index in the list of the element from which the other elements get subtracted. I still don't know what you're trying to say for the row corresponding to Mike.

1. Create a `list1` of the third column from your data frame (Trigger)
2. Create a `list2` of the second column from your data frame (Dates)
3. Create an empty `list3` which will be your Dates_Difference column.
4. Enumerate the `list1` with a variable `i` and iterate through the `list2` inside it with a variable `j` and keep appending `list2[i] - list2[j]` to `list3`. Handle the cases when `i = NaN` accordingly.
5. Insert `list3` as a new column to your data frame with the name Dates_diff

Hope it helps :)